# Access delete query not deleting right record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This should not be that hard.  I'm simply trying to delete a record from a table, where the ID is equal to a form value.  Done it a thousand times.

In this case, the FIRST record in the table is being deleted, NOT the selected one in the form.  I've looked at table properties, form properties and tried every delete query variation I'm aware of.

I've tried building a delete query in Query Design and executing that.  I've tried a SQL statement by passing the Access query.  And I've tried writing the SQL to the Access delete query.  All results are the same. 
 HOWEVER, if I hard code the ID number in the Access Delete Query, the correct record deletes as expected.  Here's a few I've tried:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " _
& "tblCourse WHERE coCourseID = " & coCourseID & ";"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM " _
    & "tblCourse WHERE coCourseID = " & coCourseID & ";"

CurrentDb.QueryDefs("dqryDeleteCourse").Sql = "DELETE * FROM tblCourse WHERE 
coCourseID = " & coCourseID & ";"

dbs.Execute dqryDeleteCourse
```

In all cases, the variable IS populating correctly.

Here's the Query Design of the dqry (this does not work):
  Field:  coCourseID
  Table: tblCourse
  Delete: WHERE
  Criteria:  [Forms]![frmCourseEdit]![coCourseID]

(I use this method of Criteria = form object value all throughout this application without an issue)

When Criteria = 1003 (hardcoded), it works.

Any troubleshooting ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ```[Forms]![frmCourseEdit]![coCourseID]!Value```?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print(coCourseID)` (or put a breakpoint on the `DoCmd.RunSQL` line) before you execute the SQL to verify the value of `coCourseID`.

Comment: I just did.  The correct record number (1003) is displayed in the Immediate Window, but again, record 1001 was deleted.  This is not that hard.  I'm really pulling my hair out!

Comment: @Anand, Yes, I did try that (though it has to be .value, not !value.  Same result I'm afraid.

Comment: Agree, should be easy but cannot replicate issue and see no problems with code. The wildcard * is not needed but should not hurt. If you want to provide db for analysis, I recommend Box.com fileshare site. Post link to file.

Comment: Not sure what your overall design is, is it possible to create a query based on the dataset feeding the form to get said 'first' record without depending upon the variable?

Comment: You can use the TOP keyword to isolate any number of records.  TOP 1 would return the first record.  I've not done this in this case of course.